# JPopupMenu know which JMenuItem are clicked

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jpopupmenu

my question in very simple. I have a `JPopupMenu` that shown two `JMenuItem`. The only way I have found to know which item are clicked using

```
class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Selected: " + e.getActionCommand());    
  }
}
```

but the command `e.getActionCommand()` print the text inside the item. I would like get an index `from 0 to n` to known which item are clicked and not the text (that can be modified).
Is it possible ?

Comment: Because I need to get an `int` and not a String... in my case with an `int` would be easier. But if isn't possible I have already found a workaround.

Comment: I'm sorry for trying to help

Comment: The problem, I can think of several, but none my be helpful and could simply be waste of each others time...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You Could...

Place each `JMenuItem` in a `Map`, with the `int` value you want

```
Map<JMenuItem, Integer> menuMap = new HashMap<JMenuItem, Integer>(25);
//...
JMenuItem item1 = ...
menuMap.put(item, 0);
JMenuItem item2 = ...
menuMap.put(item, 1);
```

Then in the `ActionListener`, you would simply look it up based on the source of the event...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem item = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
    int index = menuMap.get(item);
```

### You Could...

Use a `List` and determine the index of the `JMenuItem` within the list...

```
List<JMenuItem> menuList = new ArrayList<JMenuItem>(25);
//...
JMenuItem item1 = ...
menuList.add(item);
JMenuItem item2 = ...
menuList.add(item);

//...

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem item = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
    int index = menuList.indexOf(item);
```

### You Could...

Make use of the [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) API

```
public class IndexedAction extends AbstractAction {
    private int index;
    public IndexedAction(int index, String name) {
        this.index = index;
        putValue(NAME, name);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Use the index some how...
    }
}

//...

JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
menu.add(new IndexedAction(0, "Item 1"));
menu.add(new IndexedAction(1, "Item 2"));
menu.addSeparator();
menu.add(new IndexedAction(2, "Item 3"));
menu.add(new IndexedAction(3, "Item 4"));
```

### You Could...

Set the `actionCommand` property of the items...

```
JPopupMenu pm = ...;
pm.add("Item 1").setActionCommand("0");
pm.add("Item 2").setActionCommand("1");
menu.addSeparator();
pm.add("Item 3").setActionCommand("2");
pm.add("Item 4").setActionCommand("3");
```

The problem with this is you're going to have to parse the `actionCommand` of the `ActionEvent` back to an `int`...not a really sound proof solution...

### You Could...

Set the `clientProperty` of each `JMenuItem`

```
JPopupMenu pm = ...;
pm.add("Item 1").putClientProperty("keyValue", 0);
pm.add("Item 2").putClientProperty("keyValue", 1);
menu.addSeparator();
pm.add("Item 3").putClientProperty("keyValue", 2);
pm.add("Item 4").putClientProperty("keyValue", 3);
```

But this gets messy...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem item = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
    Object value = item.getClientProperty("keyValue");
    if (value instanceof Integer) {
        int index = ((Integer)value).intValue();
```

There's probably other solutions, but without knowing why you want to do this, it makes it impossible to make an accurate suggestion...sorry

Answer (score 2):

The code below shows how to get the index of selected `JMenuItem`:

```
      class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JMenuItem menuitem=(JMenuItem) e.getSource();
                JPopupMenu popupMenu =(JPopupMenu) menuitem.getParent();
                int index= popupMenu.getComponentIndex(menuitem);
                System.out.println("index:"+index);
            }
      }
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is it does not take into account things  like `JSeparator`s or other components that might be on the popup

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are right, adding an `instanceof JMenuItem` should fix that, shouldn't it?

Comment: The problem, not knowing why the OP want's the `int` value, getting the component index may not result in what they are after...

Comment: @MadProgrammer It seems he doesn't want to share that.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't we do:

```
menu.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()
```

which returns an `int`?