# managing a swing Interface with JButtons performing actions

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I am doing a Battleship game with Java Swing GUI. There are several things i still need to implement, but right now i am trying to let the user select a cell in interface and make this action actually do something in the Matrix board of the player. In the user interface, every cell is actually a JButton, which is in a Matrix (10x10).I have a Class Player which have a atribute Board that is a matrix (10x10) with 0 in every position not selected, 1 in every position with a boat and -1 in every position shoted by the enemy. I could not figure out a way to connect a button press ActionPerformed with the player board. Tried some things. In the ActionPerformed tried to send to a method "select" the i and j of the position but all i got was a "in order for an inner class to access a local variable, that variable MUST be declared final or be "effectively final" warning. What should i do?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
          tabuleiro1[i][j] = new JButton(); //the board visual interface of player1
          tabuleiro1[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                     selected(((JButton)e.getSource()),i,j);//i cant send those i,j, which are very important
// to know where in the actually board of the player i should do a change
                }
           });
          tabuleiro2[i][j] = new JButton(); // same here above, but for player2
     }
}
//where this became a actual graphical interface (just to point)
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
         jPanel1.add(tabuleiro1[i][j]);
         jPanel2.add(tabuleiro2[i][j]);
     }
}
//what i need
public void selected(JButton B, int i, int j){
        if(player.getBoard().getPositions()[i][j]==0){
            B.setBackground(Color.black);//just to change the color of button, as a test
        }
        else if(player.getBoard().getPositions()[i][j]==1){
            B.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Already shoted");//not yet supported, just a way to test too
        }
    }
```

The problem is i cant pass the i,j to selected cause of "in order for an inner class to access a local variable, that variable MUST be declared final or be "effectively final"". How can i get the i,j of the JButton clicked?

Comment: You could use a `Map` to map a `JButton` to `Point`, then when clicked, lookup the associated `Point` which will give the grid x/y corrdinates. You could make use of the `actionCommand` support of the button to store the x/y corrdinates as a `String`, but then you'd need to parse this when you need it. You could make use of the `Action` API and seed the x/y corrdinates as properties to the class. You could use the `clientProperty` support to associate the `Point` with the button.

Comment: [For examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656891/jpopupmenu-know-which-jmenuitem-are-clicked/22660668#22660668)

Comment: I appreciate your ideas. Gonna try all the suggestions e figure out the simpler for me.

Answer (score -2):

One way to do is to extend the JButton class.  The subclass has a constructor with i and j paramters.  When buttons of this class are created, i and j values are passed to the buttons.  See example below:

[image]

```
class Tile extends JButton {
  int i, j;
  Tile(int i, int j){
    this.i=i;
    this.j=j;
  }
}
public class App extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  
  Tile[][] buttons = new Tile[10][10];
  
  public App(){
    this.setSize(200, 200);
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<10;j++){
        buttons[i][j] = new Tile(i,j);
        buttons[i][j].addActionListener(this);
        this.getContentPane().add(buttons[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Tile t = (Tile) e.getSource();
    t.setBackground(Color.red);
    System.out.println(t.i + ":" + t.j);
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args){
    new App().setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Console:

```
3:3
5:4
2:5
5:8
6:2
4:6
7:6
```

Comment: I wouldn't, lots of reasons, but simply, there's easier ways to do it, like using a lookup machanism (ie `Map), using `Action`s, using `clientProperty` or even just the `actionCommand` property. IMHO, extending a class wouldn't be my first port of call.  All the other suggestion also mean you're not stuck to using a button to represent the state - but that's me

Comment: Very intuitive. Gonna try your suggestion. Thanks Cheng